# android socket connection

Tags: android, sockets, wifi

I have created a client-server wi-fi app. The problem is when server connection is lost, it does not throws any IO Exception during read/write operation in socket. How can i identify that the server connection was lost within my app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this

```
private boolean checkInternetConnection()
{
    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService (Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    return conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: is this checks only Wi-Fi connectivity?

Comment: How I know, it is checking all the connectivity.

Comment: i mean, i just need to check whether that socket with server still exist or not?

Comment: No it checking only your connectivity, it is  checking your connection with server, i.e. if your wi-fi connectivity lost it will return false;